Using intellij plugin BrowserUtil.browse directs same window
Using Intellij Community Version, I want to write a plugin that directs first to a login page.
once logged in to direct to another page in the same browser window/session.
Is this even possible ?
I have in the menu option =

@Override public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
BrowserUtil.browse("https://example.com/login"); }

but then if I try to redirect how could I do this ?

@Override
public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) { BrowserUtil.open("https://example.com.com/app/projects/730/exploration/user-journeys/sankey");}

Just opens another window that is not logged in.
Is there some way of sending the login or session or just redirect in the same window via my intellij plugin commands...
not sure intellij-community/platform/platform-api/src/com/intellij/ide
/BrowserUtil.java     is the answer.
